# Unable to locate package buildah

Tags: docker, ubuntu, azul-zulu, buildah

I am trying to build Ubuntu image with a possibility to build Docker images on it. The tool that I want to use for it is [buildah](https://github.com/containers/buildah). However when my docker build executes the installation command: `sudo apt-get -y install buildah` I get this error: *Unable to locate package buildah*. My base image is: [Zulu OpenJDK from Azul](https://github.com/zulu-openjdk/zulu-openjdk/blob/master/debian/11.0.9-11.43.21/Dockerfile). I can clearly see that the requested package is in the central [Ubuntu repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/builda) so I really do not understand why it can not find it.

Comment: have you ran `apt-get update` before `apt-get install` ?

Comment: Yes, I do run apt-get update before apt-get install

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Zulu Dockerfile that you are using is based on Debian Buster (10.0), not Ubuntu.  This is indicated by the first line of the file:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
```

Looking at the `buildah` installation instructions on Github (https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/master/install.md), we find that `buildah` is only available in the Bullseye testing branch for Debian not from the default package repo.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and append the following line:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

Run `sudo apt update` and then you can install buildah using `sudo apt-get install buildah`